# Problemas com selectOneMenu em Jsf 1.2

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

Preciso usar JSF 1.2 por restrição do cliente.

Estou usando `selectOneMenu` para selecionar o tipo de pessoa (Física/Jurídica) e mudar a máscara dinamicamente com `<a4j:support>` e está funcionando.

Mas o Bean ao receber o valor CNPJ está vindo nulo, veja abaixo:

```
<rich:column id="col-id-pessoa">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="tipo-pessoa"
                     value="#{atividadeController.tipoPessoa}"
        valueChangeListener="#{atividadeController.mudancaTipoPessoaListener() }">
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Física"   itemValue="F" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Jurídica" itemValue="J" />
    <a4j:support event="onclick" ajaxSingle="true" reRender="colCPF">
    </a4j:support>
                                                                     </h:selectOneMenu>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="colCPF">
    <h:inputText value="#{atividadeController.cpf }"
                id="cpf" styleClass="cpf" required="true"
                requiredMessage="CPF/CNPJ é um dado obrigatório"
                rendered="#{atividadeController.tipoPessoa eq 'F' }">
    </h:inputText>
    <h:inputText value="#{atividadeController.cnpj }"
                id="cnpj" styleClass="cnpj" required="true"
                requiredMessage="CPF/CNPJ é um dado obrigatório"
                rendered="#{atividadeController.tipoPessoa eq 'J' }">
</h:inputText>
</rich:column>
```

As máscaras funcionam, mas no Bean o valor do campo `cnpj` está vindo nulo, `cpf` vem preenchido corretamente.

```
package com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.controller;
```

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.AnaliseRHBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.AtividadeBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.AtividadeEnvolvidosBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.EmpresaBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.PrioridadeBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.SolicitanteBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.StatusAtividadeBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.TipoAtividadeBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.bo.UsuarioBO;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.AnaliseRH;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.Atividade;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.AtividadeEnvolvidos;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.Empresa;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.Prioridade;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.Solicitante;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.StatusAtividade;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.TipoAtividade;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.entity.Usuario;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.exception.NegocioException;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.util.ValidaCNPJ;
import com.porto.npf.sgpsweb.util.ValidaCPF;

public class AtividadeController extends BaseController implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3084067945627378605L;
    private static final String OUTCOME = "formAtividade";
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(true);

```
// Lista de empresas
private List<Empresa> listaDeEmpresasAtivas = new ArrayList<Empresa>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectEmpresasAtivas;

// Lista de Solicitantes
private List<Solicitante> listaDeSolicitantesAtivos = new ArrayList<Solicitante>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos;

// Lista de status da atividade
private List<StatusAtividade> listaDeStatusAtivos = new ArrayList<StatusAtividade>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectStatusAtivos;

// Lista de prioridades
private List<Prioridade> listaPrioridadesAtivas = new ArrayList<Prioridade>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas;

// Lista de Responsável pela atividade
private List<Usuario> listaUsuariosAtivos = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectUsuariosAtivos;

// Lista de Tipos de Atividades
private List<TipoAtividade> listaTiposAtividadeAtivos = new ArrayList<TipoAtividade>();
private List<SelectItem> listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos;

// Lista de Envolvidos na análise
private List<AtividadeEnvolvidos> listaDeEnvolvidos = new ArrayList<AtividadeEnvolvidos>();

// Lista de CPF de analises de RH
private List<AnaliseRH> listaAnaliseRH = new ArrayList<AnaliseRH>();

// Business Objects
private EmpresaBO empBO;
private AtividadeBO atividadeBO;
private SolicitanteBO solicitanteBO;
private StatusAtividadeBO sttBO;
private PrioridadeBO priorBO;
private UsuarioBO usuarioBO;
private TipoAtividadeBO tipoBO;
private AtividadeEnvolvidosBO envolvidosBO;
private AnaliseRHBO analiseRHBO;

// Atributos
private Integer empresaId;
private Integer id;
private String codigoAtividade;
private Integer solicitanteId;
private Integer statusatividadeId;
private String descricaoAtividade;
private Integer prioridadeId;
private Integer responsavelatividadeId;
private String responsavelRegistro;
private Integer tipoatividadeId;
private Date dataCriacao;
private Date dataSolicitacao;
private Date dataPrevia;
private Date dataInicio;
private Date dataPrevicaoEntrega;
private Date dataConclusao;
private String solicitacao;
private String descricao;
private String conclusao;

// Atributo que controla a aba
private String abaAtiva;

// Envolvidos
private String tipoPessoa;
private String cpf;
private String cnpj;
private String nomeEnvolvido;
private String styleClassTipoPessoa;

/**
 * Construtor
 */
public AtividadeController() {
    // Instancia todos os objetos de negócio
    empBO = new EmpresaBO();
    atividadeBO = new AtividadeBO();
    solicitanteBO = new SolicitanteBO();
    sttBO = new StatusAtividadeBO();
    priorBO = new PrioridadeBO();
    usuarioBO = new UsuarioBO();
    tipoBO = new TipoAtividadeBO();
    envolvidosBO = new AtividadeEnvolvidosBO();
    analiseRHBO = new AnaliseRHBO();

    // Inicializa o bean
    inicializaBean();
} // fim do construtor

/**
 * Método que inicializa o Bean
 * 
 */
private void inicializaBean(){
    //listaDeEmpresasAtivas.clear();
    //listaSelectEmpresasAtivas.clear();
    Integer idSessao = (Integer) getAtributoSessao("ssIdAtividade");

    // Se foi passado como parâmetro o id para edição, então pesquisa e preenche a tela
    if (idSessao > 0) {
        Atividade atividade = new Atividade();
        try {
            // Obtém a atividade e popula o form
            atividade = atividadeBO.getAtividadePorId(idSessao);
            id = atividade.getId();
            empresaId = atividade.getEmpresa().getId();
            codigoAtividade = atividade.getCodigoAtividade();
            solicitanteId = atividade.getSolicitante().getId();
            statusatividadeId = atividade.getStatusAtividade().getId();
            descricaoAtividade = atividade.getDescricaoAtividade();
            prioridadeId = atividade.getPrioridade().getId();
            if (atividade.getResponsavelAtividade()==null) {
                responsavelatividadeId = 0;
            } else {
                responsavelatividadeId = atividade.getResponsavelAtividade().getId();
            }
            responsavelRegistro = atividade.getResponsavelRegistro();
            tipoatividadeId = atividade.getTipoAtividade().getId();
            dataCriacao = atividade.getDataCriacao();
            dataSolicitacao = atividade.getDataSolicitacao();
            dataPrevia = atividade.getDataPrevia();
            dataInicio = atividade.getDataInicio();
            dataPrevicaoEntrega = atividade.getDataPrevisaoEntrega();
            dataConclusao = atividade.getDataConclusao();
            solicitacao = atividade.getSolicitacao();
            descricao = atividade.getDescricao();
            conclusao = atividade.getConclusao();

            // Define a aba ao iniciar
            abaAtiva = "aba1";
            styleClassTipoPessoa = "cpf";

        } catch (NegocioException e) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Problemas ao obter Atividade");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } // 

    // Envolvidos
    tipoPessoa = "F";

} // fim do método inicializaBean

/**
 * Método que é acionado quando existe mudança no tipo de pessoa no cadastro de envolvidos
 * 
 * @return
 */
public void mudancaTipoPessoaListener(ValueChangeEvent event) {
    tipoPessoa = (String) event.getNewValue();
    if ("F".equals(tipoPessoa)) {
        styleClassTipoPessoa = "cpf";
    } else {
        styleClassTipoPessoa = "cnpj";
    }
} // fim do método mudancaTipoPessoaListener

/**
 * Método que processa a persistencia dos dados do envolvido
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String salvarEnvolvido(){
    AtividadeEnvolvidos atvEnvolvidos = new AtividadeEnvolvidos();

    /*
    if (!"".equals(cpf)) {
        atvEnvolvidos.setCpfCnpj(cpf);
    } else {
        atvEnvolvidos.setCpfCnpj(cnpj);
    }
    */

    if ("J".equals(tipoPessoa)) {
        if (ValidaCNPJ.isCNPJ(cnpj)) {
            atvEnvolvidos.setCpfCnpj(cnpj);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("CNPJ Inválido");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            return null;
        }
    } else {
        if (ValidaCPF.isCPF(cpf)) {
            atvEnvolvidos.setCpfCnpj(cpf);
        } else {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("CPF Inválido");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            return null;
        }
    }

    atvEnvolvidos.setNome(nomeEnvolvido);
    atvEnvolvidos.setTipoPessoa(tipoPessoa);
    atvEnvolvidos.setAtividadeId(id);

    try {
        envolvidosBO.salvar(atvEnvolvidos);
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Problemas ao Salvar o Envolvido");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    abaAtiva = "aba2";
    return null;
}

/**
 * Listener que processa a limpeza do formulário
 */
public void iniciarEnvolvidosListerner(){
    tipoPessoa = "F";
    nomeEnvolvido = "";
    cpf = "";
    cnpj = "";
}

/**
 * Método que busca o objeto no BD e preenche a tela para edição
 * 
 * @param id
 * @return
 */
public String editarEnvolvido(Integer id){
    AtividadeEnvolvidos envolvidos = new AtividadeEnvolvidos();
    try {
        envolvidos = envolvidosBO.getAtividadeEnvolvidosPorId(id);
        tipoPessoa = envolvidos.getTipoPessoa();
        if ("F".equals(envolvidos.getTipoPessoa())) {
            cpf    = envolvidos.getCpfCnpj();
        } else {
            cnpj   = envolvidos.getCpfCnpj();
        }
        nomeEnvolvido = envolvidos.getNome();
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Problemas ao Salvar o Envolvido");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return OUTCOME;
} // fim do método editarEnvolvido

/**
 * Método que atualiza o tempo gasto
 * 
 * @return
 */
public String atualizarTempoGastoNaAtividade() {
    return OUTCOME;
} // fim do método atualizarTempoGastoNaAtividade

// Botão voltar
public String voltar() {
    String retorno = OUTCOME;
    String tipoUsuario = (String) getAtributoSessao("tipoUsuario");
    if (tipoUsuario.equals("C")) {
        retorno = "areaPrincipalCliente";
    }
    return retorno;
} // fim do método voltar

// Getters e Setters

public List<Empresa> getListaDeEmpresasAtivas() {
    return listaDeEmpresasAtivas;
}

public void setListaDeEmpresasAtivas(List<Empresa> listaDeEmpresasAtivas) {
    this.listaDeEmpresasAtivas = listaDeEmpresasAtivas;
}

public Integer getEmpresaId() {
    return empresaId;
}

public void setEmpresaId(Integer empresaId) {
    this.empresaId = empresaId;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectEmpresasAtivas() {
    try {
        listaDeEmpresasAtivas = empBO.getListaEmpresasAtivas();
        listaSelectEmpresasAtivas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaDeEmpresasAtivas.size());
        for (Empresa e : listaDeEmpresasAtivas) {
            listaSelectEmpresasAtivas.add(new SelectItem(e.getId(), e
                    .getNomeEmpresa()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Empresas Ativas");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectEmpresasAtivas;
}

public void setListaSelectEmpresasAtivas(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectEmpresasAtivas) {
    this.listaSelectEmpresasAtivas = listaSelectEmpresasAtivas;
}

public String getCodigoAtividade() {
    return codigoAtividade;
}

public void setCodigoAtividade(String codigoAtividade) {
    this.codigoAtividade = codigoAtividade;
}

public List<Solicitante> getListaDeSolicitantesAtivos() {
    return listaDeSolicitantesAtivos;
}

public void setListaDeSolicitantesAtivos(
        List<Solicitante> listaDeSolicitantesAtivos) {
    this.listaDeSolicitantesAtivos = listaDeSolicitantesAtivos;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectSolicitantesAtivos() {
    try {
        listaDeSolicitantesAtivos = solicitanteBO
                .getListaTodosSolicitantesAtivos();
        listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaDeSolicitantesAtivos.size());
        for (Solicitante s : listaDeSolicitantesAtivos) {
            listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos.add(new SelectItem(s.getId(), s
                    .getDescricaoSolicitante()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Solicitantes Ativos");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos;
}

public void setListaSelectSolicitantesAtivos(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos) {
    this.listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos = listaSelectSolicitantesAtivos;
}

public Integer getSolicitanteId() {
    return solicitanteId;
}

public void setSolicitanteId(Integer solicitanteId) {
    this.solicitanteId = solicitanteId;
}

public List<StatusAtividade> getListaDeStatusAtivos() {
    return listaDeStatusAtivos;
}

public void setListaDeStatusAtivos(List<StatusAtividade> listaDeStatusAtivos) {
    this.listaDeStatusAtivos = listaDeStatusAtivos;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectStatusAtivos() {
    try {
        listaDeStatusAtivos = sttBO.getListaStatusAtividadeAtivos();
        listaSelectStatusAtivos = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaDeStatusAtivos.size());
        for (StatusAtividade s : listaDeStatusAtivos) {
            listaSelectStatusAtivos.add(new SelectItem(s.getId(), s
                    .getDescricaoStatus()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Status das Atividades Ativos");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectStatusAtivos;
}

public void setListaSelectStatusAtivos(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectStatusAtivos) {
    this.listaSelectStatusAtivos = listaSelectStatusAtivos;
}

public Integer getStatusatividadeId() {
    return statusatividadeId;
}

public void setStatusatividadeId(Integer statusatividadeId) {
    this.statusatividadeId = statusatividadeId;
}

public String getDescricaoAtividade() {
    return descricaoAtividade;
}

public void setDescricaoAtividade(String descricaoAtividade) {
    this.descricaoAtividade = descricaoAtividade;
}

public Integer getPrioridadeId() {
    return prioridadeId;
}

public void setPrioridadeId(Integer prioridadeId) {
    this.prioridadeId = prioridadeId;
}

public List<Prioridade> getListaPrioridadesAtivas() {
    return listaPrioridadesAtivas;
}

public void setListaPrioridadesAtivas(
        List<Prioridade> listaPrioridadesAtivas) {
    this.listaPrioridadesAtivas = listaPrioridadesAtivas;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectPrioridadesAtivas() {
    try {
        listaPrioridadesAtivas = priorBO.getListaPrioridadesAtivas();
        listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaPrioridadesAtivas.size());
        for (Prioridade p : listaPrioridadesAtivas) {
            listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas.add(new SelectItem(p.getId(), p
                    .getDescricaoPrioridade()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Status das Atividades Ativos");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas;
}

public void setListaSelectPrioridadesAtivas(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas) {
    this.listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas = listaSelectPrioridadesAtivas;
}

public Integer getResponsavelatividadeId() {
    return responsavelatividadeId;
}

public void setResponsavelatividadeId(Integer responsavelatividadeId) {
    this.responsavelatividadeId = responsavelatividadeId;
}

public List<Usuario> getListaUsuariosAtivos() {
    return listaUsuariosAtivos;
}

public void setListaUsuariosAtivos(List<Usuario> listaUsuariosAtivos) {
    this.listaUsuariosAtivos = listaUsuariosAtivos;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectUsuariosAtivos() {
    try {
        listaUsuariosAtivos = usuarioBO.getListaUsuariosInternosEAtivos();
        listaSelectUsuariosAtivos = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaUsuariosAtivos.size());
        for (Usuario u : listaUsuariosAtivos) {
            listaSelectUsuariosAtivos.add(new SelectItem(u.getId(), u
                    .getNomeUsuario()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Status das Atividades Ativos");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectUsuariosAtivos;
}

public void setListaSelectUsuariosAtivos(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectUsuariosAtivos) {
    this.listaSelectUsuariosAtivos = listaSelectUsuariosAtivos;
}

public String getResponsavelRegistro() {
    return responsavelRegistro;
}

public void setResponsavelRegistro(String responsavelRegistro) {
    this.responsavelRegistro = responsavelRegistro;
}

public Integer getTipoatividadeId() {
    return tipoatividadeId;
}

public void setTipoatividadeId(Integer tipoatividadeId) {
    this.tipoatividadeId = tipoatividadeId;
}

public List<TipoAtividade> getListaTiposAtividadeAtivos() {
    return listaTiposAtividadeAtivos;
}

public void setListaTiposAtividadeAtivos(
        List<TipoAtividade> listaTiposAtividadeAtivos) {
    this.listaTiposAtividadeAtivos = listaTiposAtividadeAtivos;
}

public List<SelectItem> getListaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos() {
    try {
        listaTiposAtividadeAtivos = tipoBO.getListaTipoAtividadesAtivos();
        listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos = new ArrayList<SelectItem>(
                listaTiposAtividadeAtivos.size());
        for (TipoAtividade t : listaTiposAtividadeAtivos) {
            listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos.add(new SelectItem(t.getId(),
                    t.getDescricaoTipoAtividade()));
        }
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Tipos das Atividades Ativos");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos;
}

public void setListaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos(
        List<SelectItem> listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos) {
    this.listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos = listaSelectTiposAtividadesAtivos;
}

public Date getDataCriacao() {
    return dataCriacao;
}

public void setDataCriacao(Date dataCriacao) {
    this.dataCriacao = dataCriacao;
}

public Date getDataSolicitacao() {
    return dataSolicitacao;
}

public void setDataSolicitacao(Date dataSolicitacao) {
    this.dataSolicitacao = dataSolicitacao;
}

public Date getDataPrevia() {
    return dataPrevia;
}

public void setDataPrevia(Date dataPrevia) {
    this.dataPrevia = dataPrevia;
}

public Date getDataInicio() {
    return dataInicio;
}

public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
    this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
}

public Date getDataPrevicaoEntrega() {
    return dataPrevicaoEntrega;
}

public void setDataPrevicaoEntrega(Date dataPrevicaoEntrega) {
    this.dataPrevicaoEntrega = dataPrevicaoEntrega;
}

public Date getDataConclusao() {
    return dataConclusao;
}

public void setDataConclusao(Date dataConclusao) {
    this.dataConclusao = dataConclusao;
}

public String getSolicitacao() {
    return solicitacao;
}

public void setSolicitacao(String solicitacao) {
    this.solicitacao = solicitacao;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}

public String getConclusao() {
    return conclusao;
}

public void setConclusao(String conclusao) {
    this.conclusao = conclusao;
}

public List<AtividadeEnvolvidos> getListaDeEnvolvidos() {
    try {
        listaDeEnvolvidos = envolvidosBO.getListaAtividadeEnvolvidosPorAtividadeId(id);
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(
                "Problemas ao obter a lista de Envolvidos nesta Atividade");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaDeEnvolvidos;
}

public void setListaDeEnvolvidos(List<AtividadeEnvolvidos> listaDeEnvolvidos) {
    this.listaDeEnvolvidos = listaDeEnvolvidos;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTipoPessoa() {
    return tipoPessoa;
}

public void setTipoPessoa(String tipoPessoa) {
    this.tipoPessoa = tipoPessoa;
}


public String getNomeEnvolvido() {
    return nomeEnvolvido;
}

public void setNomeEnvolvido(String nomeEnvolvido) {
    this.nomeEnvolvido = nomeEnvolvido;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}

public String getCnpj() {
    return cnpj;
}

public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
    this.cnpj = cnpj;
}




public String getAbaAtiva() {
    return abaAtiva;
}

public void setAbaAtiva(String abaAtiva) {
    this.abaAtiva = abaAtiva;
}

public String getStyleClassTipoPessoa() {
    return styleClassTipoPessoa;
}

public void setStyleClassTipoPessoa(String styleClassTipoPessoa) {
    this.styleClassTipoPessoa = styleClassTipoPessoa;
}

public List<AnaliseRH> getListaAnaliseRH() {
    try {
        listaAnaliseRH = analiseRHBO.getListaAnaliseRHPorAtividadeId(id);
    } catch (NegocioException e) {
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Problemas ao obter a Lista de Análises do RH");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaAnaliseRH;
}

public void setListaAnaliseRH(List<AnaliseRH> listaAnaliseRH) {
    this.listaAnaliseRH = listaAnaliseRH;
}
```

}

Comment: Abaixo segue o código

Comment: Como esta o atributo cnpj e cpf no managed bean 'atividadeController' ?

Comment: Alexandre, tenho os getters e setters no bean. Quando selecionado cpf o valor é atribuído normalmente. Mas quando o cnpj é selecionado, no bean ele está nulo. Como disse a máscara funciona, apenas o bean parece que não reconhece o valor do cnpj.

Comment: Ok. Tu pode mostrar o código do managed bean?

Comment: Alexandre, eu acrescentei o código.

Comment: Marcelo podes [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar informação, em vez de colocar respostas com informação que faz parte da pergunta.

Comment: @MarceloGomes, sugiro colocar os arquivos completos, a classe responsável e o html completo. Faça exatamente como o Sergio mencionou acima.

Comment: Coloquei o Bean inteiro. Lembrando que estou usando jsf 1.2 o Bean está com escopo "request".

Answer (score 0):

Ao chamar o segundo método (que não vi onde está o método ou a chamada) você deveria utilizar o `setPropertyActionListener` ou uma alternativa para definir o valor do CNPJ no bean denovo.

Comment: Shura16 eu vi alguns exemplos e tentei implementar e não deu certo. Todos os exemplos que vi o <f:setPropertyActionListener> está alinhado com commandLink ou commandButton. Quando colocado fora deste alinhamento dá erro. Vc teria como me dizer, no código acima, onde devo implementar?

Comment: Exatamente deve ter um form e um commandLink ou commandoButton. Onde você está chamando o método acima?

Comment: No meu caso então não funcionará, pois a chamada do listener que muda o estado do atribudo {tipoPessoa} é realizado pelo selectOneMenu.

Comment: Passa o valor de novo por parâmetro no método então.

Comment: Vou tentar e posto o resultado.